# Java regex to split string with variable spaces and delimiter

Tags: java, string, split, pattern-matching

Given a one-line string like

```
a   b c d => e f g   1 2
```

with dual delimiters (`space` and `=>`) the pattern

`" +( +|\\=> *)?"`

produces the following 9 fields as the output of `String.split()` in `Java`:

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 1, 2`

However, if the input string uses a notation like "1 M" to represent number "1 million", i.e.

`a   b c d => e f g   1 m 2`

the pattern, not surprisingly, produces 10 fields (`m` being the extra one).

Can the pattern be modified to reliably group together `1` and `m` as `1 m`, everything else being the same, in `String.split()`?

Comment: "Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This splits the input according to the `=>` or spaces which aren't followed by `m`.

```
String s = "a b c d => e f g 1 m 2";
String[] parts = s.split("\\s*=>\\s*|\\s+(?!m)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, 1 m, 2]
```

**OR**

```
String s = "a b c d => e f g 1 m 2";
String[] parts = s.split("\\s*=>\\s*|(?<!\\d)\\s+(?!m)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Comment: The original regex you suggested, `\s+(?!m)`, leaves empty tokens, so I corrected it by adding the `\s*` symbols around the `=>` delimiter, but meanwhile you also fixed it. Nice! :-)

Comment: yep, i realized later only. So i added `*` after `\\s` which means zero or more space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Split on spaces that either aren't preceded by a digit or aren't followed by "m":

```
str.split("((?<!\\d) | (?!m))+(\\=> *)?"
```

FYI the " +" as an alternation in the optional group is redundant because the initial " +" will consume all spaces.

Comment: Yes, I originally had the first ` +` group with a non-greedy quantifier, i.e. ` +?`. Your proposal seems to work, too, so thanks and +1 as well. :-)